# Dynamic Caching using Workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am using workbox routing for dynamic caching. I don't want to give fix url as it will change based on user interaction. how can i achieve this? I am using this like below but it is fixed with one state

```
let BASE_URL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host,
    API_URL = BASE_URL + '/ab/abc/api/'
```

I want to cache all url which has /ab/abc/api/

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(API_URL, workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
  cacheName: 'abc',
  plugins: [
    new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
      maxEntries: 1
    }),
    new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
      statuses: [200]
    })
  ]
```

}));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's some more background on how Workbox's routing works available [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/route-requests#matching_a_route_with_a_regular_expression).

To answer your specific question, though, you can create a route that matches based on a regular expression, and that regular expression only needs to match a portion of the incoming URL (like, matching a common prefix or suffix).

Assuming your common prefix is `/ab/abc/api/` and that your actual API calls are for URLs that exist under that path (e.g. `/ab/abc/api/entries`, `/ab/abc/api/latest?t=1`, etc.), you could create a route like:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/ab/abc/api'),
  workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
    cacheName: 'abc',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 50
      })
    ]
}));
```

The one other thing that I changed there is the `maxEntries` for your cache expiration. Each unique URL that matches the `RegExp` will get its own cache entry, and if you set `maxEntries` to 1, then you'll only end up caching the very last URL used, with all the other entries expired after each time. I'm assuming that setting it to something higher (I used 50, but whatever makes sense for you) is more in keeping with what you intend.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! but in my case the url xyz.xy.xom is changing as per env so i am taking base url BASE_URL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host and adding it with /ab/abc/api. so that i have stored it in var. if i just use /ab/abc/api it cache url only when user visit specific module. and if url has htttps://xyz.xy.com/xy/xyz/xy/xyz/xy-xyz-xyz?startDate=01/06/2018&endDate=11/06/2018, here date will change. so do we have any option in workbox to deal with?

Comment: You can construct a `RegExp` that is as complicated as you'd like, and includes meta-characters like `^` to match at the start of a URL. Alternatively, you can create your own `matchCallback` that will use whatever logic you want at runtime (instead of a `RegExp`) to determine whether the `Route` will match. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing.Route#~matchCallback